# Text doesn't wrap correctly inside an mdframed frame (in tufte-book)

Tags: mdframed, tufte

Here's a minimal working example illustrating my problem

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
In mdframed the text is not correctly wrapped within the box, either ending 
too close to the edge or sometimes overlapping entirely
\end{mdframed} 

\end{document}
```

This produces the following

[image]

Comment: May be you could change to [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default textwidth in `tufte-book` is so small that the TeX line-breaking algorithm can't find a feasible solution for this specific piece of text and font size. As a result you get two overfull boxes, and the paragraph can't be completely contained within the `mdframed` frame.

One remedy is to invoke `\sloppy`, which relaxes some constraints of the line-breaking algorithm, at the beginning of the `mdframed` environment. Of course, as a result, the output will look a bit... well... sloppier, but the text will be less likely to cross the border of the surrounding frame.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % filler text to show the text width

\begin{mdframed}
\sloppy
In mdframed the text is not correctly wrapped within the box, either ending 
too close to the edge or sometimes overlapping entirely
\end{mdframed} 

\end{document}
```