# An annoying overflow in mdframed environment with tufte-handout

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mdframed, tufte

I'd like to highlight a text block in a [Tufte style](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) document. I defined `myblock` environment based on [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\definecolor{MyGray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.98}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\newenvironment{myblock}%
{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=MyGray,
    linecolor=MyGray,
    innerleftmargin=1.5mm,
    innerrightmargin=1mm]\begingroup}
{\endgroup\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myblock}
Hello, world! This is just a random text to show an annoying superflous
overflow in \texttt{mdframed} environment.
\end{myblock}
\marginnote{Why an overflow?}
\end{document}
```

This simple MWE generates a PDF document with an overflow at `myblock` environment.

[image]

You can see the word 'superflous' juts out over the colored box. Why do I have an overflow like this? Is there any way to keep the `myblock` text inside of the desired color box?

---

***Update:*** After reading a comment by Yiannis Lazarides, I removed `innerrightmargin` parameter to see that it's working for the first example above. But it still ends up with an overflow in the following example where I use [fontspec](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/) package for [Minion Pro font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minion_(typeface)).

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}

\definecolor{MyGray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.98}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\newenvironment{myblock}%
{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=MyGray,
    linecolor=MyGray,
    innerleftmargin=1.5mm]\begingroup}
{\endgroup\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myblock}
A vector $v$ is \emph{appropriately orthogonal} if the potential function is
still small enough to admit another orthogonal vector in the next round.
\end{myblock}
\marginnote{I'm afraid I still have an overflow after deleting
  the \texttt{innerrightmargin} parameter.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use [XeLaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) in [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) 2014 on Mac OS X. (I'm sorry for any confusion but the first example was a *minimal* document which still generates an overflow even without `fontspec` package.)

Comment: Remove or increase `innerrightmargin=1mm` by 0.5. This is a hyphenation issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `\sloppy` is the only option. as explained in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153877/10398).